Flutter: Benefit of passing DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform to Firebase.initializeApp()?
The following snippet is shown in some Firebase Flutter examples.
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);


https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core/example

What is the benefit of passing DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform to Firebase.initializeApp()?
The options parameter is nullable (optional).
I wonder if passing something called "Default..." to an optional parameter might not make a difference.

Did you try removing the optional parameter?  What did it do?  Note that DefaultFirebaseOptions is generated for you in firebase_options.dart when you run flutterfire configure, as a result of your choices.

Yes, I did. But I didn't notice any difference. My app was still successfully receiving messages. I see. Thanks for the explanation!


If you don't pass any options to Firebase.initializeApp the SDK will be initialized with the information from the GoogleService-Info.plist (iOS), GoogleServices.json (Android) or the JavaScript snippet (web).

If you pass a value for options (typically read from FirebaseOptions.dart), the SDK will be initialized with that.

If the files and the Dart code have the same values (as is typically the case when you use the flutterfire CLI to manage things), there is no real different - but passing the options will give you better debug info.


